# Angular MDBootstrap styles stop applying when page is reloaded

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I am using the MDBootstrap package (Angular version) and I am trying to apply it on the buttons of a page I am building.

At first, the page is loaded and the buttons' styles are applied, but if I reload the page, the styles are not applied anymore.
I would like to know why this happens and if there is a way to omit the MDBootstrap styling for a specific component and apply the base Bootstrap styles.

Here is the example, at first when the page is loaded once:

[image]

And then here is the same page when it's reloaded:

[image]

Notice how the two buttons change on each image.
This is the code I used to generate the header section:

```js
<div class="row align-content-between m-3 mt-4">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" size="sm"
            [routerLink]="['/admin/project-management']" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" mdbWavesEffect>
            <mdb-icon fas icon="arrow-left"></mdb-icon>
            <div class="d-none d-md-inline ml-2">Atrás</div>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col my-auto">
        <h3><strong>{{project_id != 0 ? "Modificar proyecto" : "Crear proyecto"}}</strong></h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use MDB Angular v8 or later. In this case you should use MDB component/directive syntax instead of adding classes to the button element. Correct syntax for buttons:

```
<button mdbBtn color="primary" size="sm">MDB Button</button>
```

MDB overwrite default Bootstrap styles so there is no way to have base styles on one component and material styles on the other one.